# Why can't I turn off my right click?

Tags: macos, mouse

I'm running 10.10, and have a wireless mighty mouse. I want to turn off the right click on the mouse. I went to System Settings > Mouse, and set the "Right Click" function to "Primary Button" instead of Secondary. However, this has no effect, and the right click still functions as a right click. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

For my `Magic Mouse`, Setting the `Secondary click` option to "click on left side," simply makes it so that the "right click" (contextual) behavior is reversed.  i.e. *left-clicking* brings up a menu, and *right-clicking* is a normal click.  **UN**checking the checkbox beside `Secondary Click` turns off the "right click" behavior altogether.

[image: Sys Pref]

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and back in solved the issue. Doesn't seem right that you should have to log out to apply changes to the mouse settings, but it worked.